# Node Express serving is serving build/ even without correct headers

Tags: node.js, express, authentication

So I started off with using create-react-app and created a react-app on my machine. I was able to run it on localhost and see the webpage. Next, I ran `npm run build` and let it build the `./build` directory.

I then created a file called `server.js` with the following contents:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const auth_key = require('./correct_auth.json').auth;

const app = express();
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get(
    '*',
    (req, res) => {
        const headers = req.headers;
        if (headers[`auth-token`] && headers[`auth-token`] === auth_key) {
            console.log(`auth-token: ${headers[`auth-token`]}`);
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, `build`, `index.html`));
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
    }
);

app.listen(
    process.env.PORT || 5000,
    () => {
        console.log(`Frontend start on localhost:5000.`);
    }
);
```

My goal is to only serve the webpage if a person has the correct auth-token header. However, visiting the site without the correct header or even with no header specified, the homepage is still served.

I should note that I have this running on a Ubuntu server from DigitalOcean and served to `localhost:5000` using Nginx. IE, I can visit api.XXXXX.com to visit the site, and it does not matter what headers I have, I always get served the site.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
build
correct_auth.json
node_modules
package.json
public
server.js
src
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
```

Is before you check the headers so that will serve files without checking the headers.

I would suggest making a single middleware that you put first that checks headers and, if they aren't there, then returns an appropriate error status.

For example, put this first:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const headers = req.headers;
    if (headers[`auth-token`] && headers[`auth-token`] === auth_key) {
        console.log(`auth-token: ${headers[`auth-token`]}`);
        // continue on to other routes
        next();
    } else {
        // 401 status is for not-authorized
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice. Not proficient in express/restify at all! I'll try it out

Comment: @SomeGuy - I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working correctly, I have mentioned in comments why:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const auth_key = require('./correct_auth.json').auth;

const app = express();
app.disable('x-powered-by');

// Put the header check middleware first, So all request mentioned after this code will go through this.
app.get(
    '*',
    (req, res) => {
        const headers = req.headers;
        if (headers[`auth-token`] && headers[`auth-token`] === auth_key) {
            console.log(`auth-token: ${headers[`auth-token`]}`);
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, `build`, `index.html`));
        } else {
            res.status(404).send("Authentication failed");
        }
    }
);

// This should come after the middleware.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));


app.listen(
    process.env.PORT || 5000,
    () => {
        console.log(`Frontend start on localhost:5000.`);
    }
);
```